# Copy files 3 times and rename them

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename

I would like to copy 1 file 3 times to the same folder and then rename those 3 files differently. I'd like to do this via a batch file, but i don't know where to start as i'm a complete beginner.

Eg: In a folder named Articles

The file "Data_1234567" must be copied 3 times and then rename those 3 to seperate names "DataNL_1234567" / "DataFR_1234567" / "DataEN_1234567".

Now I only have Data_1234567 but I need to copy them to 3 languages (NL/FR/EN) so I have those 4 and can delete the one without the languages after it copied & renamed the files.

Is there any way to do this with cmd/batch?

Answer (score 0):

In bash(!) I would do that:

```
cp DATA_1234567 DATANL_1234567
cp DATA_1234567 DATAFR_1234567
cp DATA_1234567 DATAEN_1234567
rm DATA_1234567
```

It's probably the same thing in Batch. save that in the batch file and execute it in the Articles Directory

Answer (score 0):

Batch-translation of Martin Erhards solution:

```
copy DATA_1234567 DATANL_1234567
copy DATA_1234567 DATAFR_1234567
copy DATA_1234567 DATAEN_1234567
del DATA_1234567
```